# Negative argument in Evil mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

Is there a way to enter negative arguments in Evil in Emacs? i.e. I want to kill 5 lines back ward, instead of `5dd`, is there something like `-5dd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs supports this. The key control + dash or `C--` invokes the command `negative-argument`, which does what you want. Unfortunately, `evil` doesn't handle negative arguments, and you get an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument characterp 67108909)
byte-code("..." [...] 9)
evil-extract-count([67108909 100])
evil-operator-range(t)
byte-code("..." [...] 5)
ad-Orig-call-interactively(evil-delete nil nil)
call-interactively(evil-delete nil nil)
```

What you want to do is not currently possible. If you want, you can contact the `evil` devs and/or file a bug report.

Comment: Yes, I did contact the dev and he added that long ago since I created this question. But thanks and I will accept your answer since it answered correctly given the time this question was created.